# Freeing char[] in C gives error and how do C compiler handle that char[]

Tags: c, pointers

Although arrays are basically pointers, freeing `char[]` in *C* gives an error.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char ptr[] = "Hello World";

    free(ptr); // this gives error at run time
}
```

**ERROR**: nexc(4212,0x10038e3c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff5fbff54c: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

The interesting part is that, it is saying I am freeing a pointer which is not allocated.
How could this happen?

But in **C++**, compiler gives me a compile time error instead.

```
int main(void) {
    char ptr[] = "Hello World";

    delete ptr; // this gives error at compile time
}
```

like,
    **`Cannot delete expression of type char[12]`**

I thought this is because of compiler handles the `char[12]` by allocating  when the function is called and deallocating the memory when the function ends. So, I write some codes after `free(ptr);` before the function ends.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char ptr[] = "Hello World";

    free(ptr); // this still gives error at run time

    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
}
```

This still gives error. How is this happening?

Comment: You only `free` what you have allocated using `malloc` (directly or indirectly).

Comment: `Although arrays are basically pointers`..stoppppp, and go back to reading your C book.

Comment: The C++ code doesn't call a function. If your re-route it via function you'll get the exact same nasal demons.

Comment: Bad dupe since this is also about C++. Since I have wiki'd my answer I can reopen with clear conscience ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only `free` what you have allocated using `malloc` (directly or indirectly) or related function (like `realloc`).

Attempting to pass a pointer not returned by `malloc` will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That you get a compiler error for `delete` in C++ is first and foremost because C and C++ are *different languages* with different rules.

And remember, an array is an array, not a pointer. Though an array can *decay* to a pointer to its first element in many situation (like when passing it to a function).

Answer (score 3):

You *only* call `free` on *dynamic memory* that you've allocated using `malloc`, `calloc` &c.. Similarly, you only call `delete` on memory allocated with `new`. In your case, the C++ compiler is required to issue a diagnostic since *pointer decay* is not permitted to occur in this particular instance, and `delete` requires a pointer type.

The behaviour on attempting to call `free` on automatic memory is *undefined*.

Comment: Not *quite* an act of kindness. It expects a pointer, and it doesn't get one. One other place where an array to pointer conversion won't occur, thankfully.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I've nicked that, and wiki'd the answer, since it's basically yours now.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to free what was malloced.
Your `ptr` is not a pointer, it is an array; an automatic local (inside main()) variable. It does not need freeing and attempting to free it is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

All the static Strings will be allocated in the data section. You can't free data from this section. Threrefore, you can free only data the you have allocated with malloc (calloc / ralloc)

Comment: "All the static Strings will be allocated in the data section.", please quote the standard that say this non sense.

Comment: Read about data segment and what it contains

Comment: Sorry, can't find any reference to "data segment" in C standard ;)

Comment: Well actually you are right.. It is not referenced in C standard. But, I tried to explain to this guy why the free is not working....

Comment: The C standard does not specify where variables are allocated. Local variables will however end up in `.stack` and string literals in `.text`. Nothing in this code will end up in `.data`. Regardless, this answer is still strange, because the OP is trying to free a local variable allocated on the stack, not the string literal itself.

Answer (score 0):

in C programming language, you cannot write the instruction you made for obvious reasons. First of all, it must be understood that a pointer variable is a variable like so many others with a type except that it contains only addresses, so it is called a pointer variable because it contains the address of what is in memory. A pointer is therefore an **address associated with a type of data** and these **two elements are inseparable.**

If the pointer variable contains the address of an object of the whole type, the pointed object is used to know how to interpret the bits that make up this object, as well as its size. The instruction you wrote is therefore a constant pointer to a character type stored somewhere in memory. The string is therefore probably placed in a read-only data segment and therefore you cannot modify the string or release its memory, because the pointer **variable does not point to a string in a space allocated dynamically** beforehand by the "malloc" or "calloc" allocation function, and that is why you have the error message.

The second error is due to a confusion of your part here too, you must understand that there is a difference between an array of characters and a pointer. In simpler terms, a pointer variable is not an array and an array is not a pointer, but access to the element is done in the same way. For an array, the characters that make up the string and end with  "\0" can be changed, but the array of characters will always point to the same address in memory and the pointer can contain another address, but beware, if you allocate the memory with a pointer and then point to other pars without releasing the memory you allocated creates a memory leak.

Answer (score -2):

This is the proper way of using delete ! you first have to let the compiler know that the variable ptr is dynamic by using new!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<new>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {

    char *ptr;
    try{
    ptr = new char [20];
    } catch(bad_alloc xa){
        cout<<"error";
    }

    ptr= "Hello World";
    cout<<ptr;

    delete [] ptr; 
}
```

Comment: You still try to delete `"Hello World"`, which is not proper.

Comment: he wants to do it ! i gave him the way!